# How can I enter the database without leaving the current psql session?

Tags: postgresql

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql
postgres=# \list
                                   List of databases
     Name     |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
--------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 linuxhowtodb | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 postgres     | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0    | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
              |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1    | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
              |          |          |
```

How can I enter the database `linuxhowtodb` without leaving the current psql session? Thanks.

Note that if I can leave the current psql session, then I can run the following to access a particular database:

```
$ psql linuxhowtodb
psql (9.6.5)
Type "help" for help.

linuxhowtodb=>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use \c:

```
postgres=# \c linuxhowtodb
```

[From the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html)

> \c or \connect [ -reuse-previous=on|off ] [ dbname [ username ] [ host ] [ port ] | conninfo ]
>
> Establishes a new connection to a PostgreSQL server. The connection parameters to use can be specified either using a positional syntax, or using conninfo connection strings.